# Stop Music Once Playing

Tags: windows, batch-file, background

I am trying to get a song to play in the background of Windows, after a little looking I found this:

```
@echo off
set file=RRLJ.mp3
(  echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
   echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
   echo Sound.Controls.play
   echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
   echo wscript.sleep 100
   echo loop
   echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
```

This works well for starting the song but I have no way of stopping it from a `.bat` file. The only way I found to cut it short is to open task manager and close it from the processes.

I have tried:

```
taskkill /im wscript.exe
```

But I keep getting something in the window saying:
Success: Sent termination sidnal to the process "wscript.exe" with PID 185448
but the music continues to play until I manually end it with task manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `/T` switch (Tree kill): terminates the specified process and any child processes which were started by it.

Here is a script to find `ProcessID` to terminate exactly needed process only using `PID`:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (
      `wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%sound.vbs%%' AND Caption like '%%script.exe%%'" get ProcessID/value ^|find /I "="`
    ) do (
        rem echo %%G
        for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%H in ("%%~G") do echo  taskkill /T /F /PID %%H  
    )
```

Note `taskkill` command is echoed merely... Remove `echo` when debugged.

Comment: I will add you to the credits of what I am making for being the first to help and for it working perfectly! So glad this is working right now, I have been trying for a while now. :D

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, and is only one line.

```
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F>nul 2>&1
```