# Process running after TASKKILL

Tags: windows, batch-file

The problem is related to the script shown below:

```
@echo on
:MAIN
start "myname" cmd /c "build\jre\bin\java -jar MainThread.jar"
timeout /t 2 >null
TASKLIST /v /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe">myfile.txt
TASKKILL /f /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myname"
TASKLIST /v /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe">myfile2.txt
:exit
```

When i execute tasklist for first time, myname is being listed in TASKLIST.After executing taskkill, myname process is not being shown in TASKLIST executed after TASKKILL but it is running.Although its name was not present in TASKLIST, it was executing.TASKKILL succeeded in removing its entry but didn't kill the process.How should I kill that process?

Comment: Disable anti-malware and try again.  If it is Avast then uninstall asap.

Comment: Kill `java` process rather than parental `cmd` one. See my answer for basic elucidation.

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you it worked. But I have one doubt.If there are multiple jars running and I want to identify one specific jar, how will I identify the jar as WINDOWTITLE shows N/A?

Comment: `wmic process where "Caption='java.exe'" get CommandLine, ProcessID /value`. Parse it using (two) `FOR /F` loops, check `CommandLine`, kill using `/PID` switch. See [my another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29271203/3439404). If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started `java` process takes up parental `cmd` window name however no sooner than latter parental `cmd` process is terminated. Proof given using substitute `where`  not having `java` installed (as `where.exe` runs for quite a while to take a screenshot or even inspect task manager).

**Test script**:

```
@echo on
:MAIN
start "myname" cmd /C where /R c:\ "whistle.*" 
@timeout /t 1 >null
TASKLIST /V /NH /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myname" /FO "CSV"
TASKLIST /v /NH /fi "IMAGENAME eq Where.exe" /FO "CSV"
TASKKILL /f /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myname"
TASKLIST /V /NH /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myname" /FO "CSV"
:exit
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\36185868.bat

==> start "myname" cmd /C where /R c:\ "whistle.*"

==> TASKLIST /V /NH /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myname" /FO "CSV"
"cmd.exe","3340","Console","1","2 240 K","Running","pcn\usern","0:00:00","myname"

==> TASKLIST /v /NH /fi "IMAGENAME eq Where.exe" /FO "CSV"
"where.exe","5188","Console","1","3 184 K","Unknown","pcn\usern","0:00:01","N/A"

==> TASKKILL /f /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myname"
SUCCESS: The process with PID 3340 has been terminated.

==> TASKLIST /V /NH /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myname" /FO "CSV"
"where.exe","5188","Console","1","3 184 K","Running","pcn\usern","0:00:01","myname"

==>
```

**Screenshot**:

[image: tasks]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping.
I used TASKKILL /f /t /fi "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq myname" command. /t is used to close all child processes and java.exe being 1 of its child process was closed.