# Stop Music Once Playing In Background PC

Tags: batch-file

Im making a cool hidden folder passworded USB drive. I have a little image that opens and I want to play music using this code.

```html
set "file=music.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
```

I want to end the music after the user types the password. Or just the ability to tell it to stop.

I found in another post on here a solution by a user but he doesnt explain how to use it. Here is the link to that post. [Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270599/stop-music-once-playing-in-background-pc) Im new to batch so just giving me a script wont help I kind of need to know how to use it.

This is the script I dont understand how to use that will stop the music. According to the post I linked.

```html
@ECHO OFF >NUL
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (
      `wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%sound.vbs%%' AND Caption like '%%script.exe%%'" get ProcessID/value ^|find /I "="`
    ) do (
        rem echo %%G
        for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%H in ("%%~G") do echo  taskkill /T /F /PID %%H  
    )
```

Here is the password code im using.

```html
@echo off
set pass= 123abc
echo Enter Password
set /p ui=
if %ui%==%pass% (goto open)
echo Wrong Password
pause
exit
:open
start folder
```

Comment: You are literally assigning quotes and a leading space to the pass variable.

Comment: Hmm? Sorry not sure what you mean. I just copy an pasted the two little bits of code Im using that other people made. Im not like super code savvy obviously. The only reason im asking on this site is because this is the site that always pops up when im looking how to do stuff... So I apologize if im in the wrong community to be asking noob questions but not sure where else to ask. 

But yeah I didn't write any of the code just pasted it from the tutorial I found. If your talking about the password bit I just pasted the raw tutorial code before removing the quotes.

Comment: Well it was a bad tutorial.

Comment: https://youtu.be/GOeLmr94i5I

This is where I got it from.

Comment: You did not follow the instructions in that video. Regardless he still uses a leading space in his example which is not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

## How to stop the music

> Note taskkill command is echoed merely... Remove echo when debugged.

see instruction by @JosefZ here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29271203/9222942
remove the 'echo' word from this line :
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%H in ("%%~G") do echo  taskkill /T /F /PID 
will becomes : 
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%H in ("%%~G") do taskkill /T /F /PID

```html
@ECHO OFF >NUL
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (
      `wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%sound.vbs%%' AND Caption like '%%script.exe%%'" get ProcessID/value ^|find /I "="`
    ) do (
        rem echo %%G
        for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%H in ("%%~G") do echo  taskkill /T /F /PID %%H  
    )
```